# Sign of $df_x$ is locally constant

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation, smooth-functions

This question is about the book *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint* of Milnor.

Let $M$ and $N$ be oriented $n$-manifolds without boundary, and assume $M$ is compact and $N$ is connected. Let $x\in M$ be a regular point of $f$, so that $df_X:TM_x\to TN_{f(x)}$ is a vector space isomorphism. Define the sign of $df_x$ to be $+1$ or $-1$ according as $df_x$ preserves or reverses orientation.

How can we show that the sign of $df_x$ is locally constant function of $x$?

Since $M$ is oriented, $x$ has a neighborhood $U$ and a diffeomorphism $h$ of $U$ onto an open subset $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$ which is orientation preserving, in the sense that for each $y\in U$ the isomorphism $dh_y$ carries the specified orientation of $TM_y$ to the standard orientation of $\Bbb R^n=TV_{h(y)}$.

I think I should use this fact, but I can't see how does this imply that the sign of $df_x$ is constant in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Since $N$ is also oriented, you similarly have a diffeomorphism $g$ which carries a neighborhood $\tilde{U}$ of $f(x)$ onto an open subset $\tilde{V}$ which is orientation preserving. Consider $\psi = g \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ and verify that $d\psi|_{h^{-1}(x)}$ is orientation preserving iff $df|_x$ is orientation preserving. How is this related to the determinant of $d\psi|_{\cdot}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some points Milnor's phantastic book is a "little short". I think you found one of these.

If $x$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f$ maps an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ diffeomorphically onto an open subset $V \subset N$. By shrinking $U$ and $V$, we may assume that there are orientation preserving diffeomorphisms $g : U \to U'$ and $h : V \to V'$, where $U', V' \subset \mathbb R^n$ are open. By shrinking $U'$,  we may assume that $U'$ is an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Now consider

$$\phi = h \circ f\mid_{U} \circ g^{-1} : U' \to V' .$$
This is a diffeomorphism. Let $D\phi_y : \mathbb R^n  \to \mathbb R^n$ denote the ordinary derivative of $\phi$ at $y \in U'$ in the sense of multivariable calculus (which is the best linear approximation of $\phi$ at $y$).
Then we have $\text{sign} df_{g(y)} = \text{sign} D\phi_y$. It therefore suffices to show that $\text{sign} D\phi_y$ is constant on $U'$.

Although Milnor doesn't mention it, it is clear that $\text{sign} D\phi_y$ is nothing else then the sign of the determinant $\det D\phi_y$. Thus it suffices to show that $\det D\phi_y$ does not change its sign on $U'$.

We know that $\phi$ is smooth, in particular continuously differentiable. Thus the map
$$D\phi : U' \to Hom(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n), y \mapsto D\phi_y$$
is continuous. Here $Hom(V,W)$ denotes the vector space of all linear maps $V \to W$ with topology induced by any norm. It is well-known that the determinant is a *continuous* function $\det : Hom(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb R$. The function $\psi =\det \circ D\phi : U ' \to \mathbb R$ does not have a zero because all $D\phi_y$ are invertible. Since $U'$ is connected, $\psi(U')$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R$ - i.e. an interval - not containing $0$. This means that the sign of $\psi(y)$ does not change on $U'$.